# How can I call MSSQL encrypted Stored Procedures from Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

There is MSSQL database with encypted Stored Procedures and my application doesn't see them (I use different jdbc drivers).

I have two question.

How can I get list of these encrypted Stored Procedures?

How can I invoke MSSQL encrypted Stored Procedures from Java?

Answer (score 2):

*How can I get list of these encrypted Stored Procedures?*

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '.' + p.name
FROM sys.procedures p
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(p.object_id, 'IsEncrypted')  = 1
```

*How can I invoke MSSQL encrypted Stored Procedures from Java?*

Should be no difference between `encrypted` and `non-encrypted` stored procedures when you invoke their from `Java`.